# Testing private types with factory constructors

Tags: f#

I've created some basic types with the intention that invalid states cannot be created. For example:

```
type PositiveDecimal = private PositiveDecimal of decimal

[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module PositiveDecimal =

    let create num =
        if num >= 0m then
            num |> PositiveDecimal |> Ok
        else
            Error.validation None (sprintf "'%f' should be positive." num)
```

This returns a `Result` with either the successfully created object or a custom error type.

I'm finding it quite awkward to unit test (using MSTest):

```
[<TestMethod>]
member __.Create() =
    let actual = 
        PositiveDecimal.create 1m
        |> Result.map PositiveDecimal.value

    // This explicit type is unfortunately required because otherwise
    // they will have different error types :(.
    let expected : Result<_, Error.Error> = Ok 1m

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual)
```

As you can see, I have to map it back to a `decimal` because I can't create a `PositiveDecimal` through another source.

Of course, I could use make the constructor `internal` and use `InternalsVisibleTo`, but that circumvents the entire point of safety if the entire assembly is allowed to ignore the factory. Is there a better way to test this?

Comment: Not really "better", but different: What about constructing the `expected` value using reflection?

Comment: That sounds good - how would I construct it? I can't find anything for taking a `UnionCaseInfo` and invoking it, do regular C# reflection methods work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't probably go so far to write a test for a smart constructor like the one you have, but if I were writing one, I'd probably just avoid the problem altogether and have a test that checks for a success given a positive argument, i.e.

```
member __.Create() =
    let res = PositiveDecimal.create 1m

    Assert.True(match res with Ok pd -> PositiveDecimal.value pd = 1M | _ -> false)
```

and another one with negative argument for a failure case (and arguably one for zero).

Or combine the two in an FsCheck property:

```
open FsCheck

let prop x = 
    let res = PositiveDecimal.create x
    match res with
    | Ok pd -> x >= 0M && PositiveDecimal.value pd = x 
    | Error _ -> x < 0M

Check.Quick prop
```